# Change width on ng-repeat elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, width, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to change the width for all the elements of a ng-repeat by calling a function.
This is my HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="fillTab">
<table>
     <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="z in downLine" class="row">
           <table class="contUser" >
              <tr>
                <td>
                   <img src="{{z.picture}}" class='mask-pic'></img>
                   <p>Sometext</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                   <p>{{z.name}}</p>
               </td>
             </tr>
           </table>
         </td>  
     </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

"downline" is an array took from a factory. The length of this array is variable

```
ejec = {
        "user0": {
            "name": "ejec0"
        },
        "user1": {
            "name": "ejec1"
        },
        "user2": {
            "name": "ejec2"
        }
}
```

So what I need is a function that maybe on click or timer, change the "width" of all my class="row" elements in my ng-repeat every time I call it:

```
 $scope.changeWidth= function() {
   $scope.x = variableNumber;
    ng-repeatElements.width = x + "px"; ????
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use ng-style, docs found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle).  If you create the style object in your controller, you can also have a function that modifies it:

```
 $scope.rowWidth = {'width': '200px' };
 function setRowWidth(newWidth){
    $scope.rowWidth = {'width': newWidth + 'px' }
 }
```

then you can add the ng-style to your html

```
<td ng-repeat="z in downLine" ng-style="rowWidth">
```

Anytime the scope variable rowWidth changes, your view will be updated by the angular render cycle.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's what I need!!! Thank you very much Aaron it's very simple solution but I broke my head all day.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngClass` :

```
$scope.changeWidth= function() {
   $scope.className = 'large';
}

<td ng-repeat="z in downLine" class="row" ng-class="className">
```

**See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/micaz/068mo973/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a flag into you controller and with $timeout/$interval or a controller function set the new value for this class variable.

See below

```js
var module = angular.module('myapp', []);
module.controller('controller', ['$scope', '$interval', function($scope, $interval){
      $scope.items = [
        {
            "name": "ejec0"
        },
        {
            "name": "ejec1"
        },
        {
            "name": "ejec2"
        }];
    $scope.class = 'base';
  
  $interval(function(){
    if($scope.class==='base') $scope.class='change';
    else $scope.class='base';
  }, 1000);
}]);
```

```css
.base{with:50px; background-color:red;}
.change{with:150px; background-color:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myapp">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="controller">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="class">
        <td ng-bind="item.name"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
</html>
```